# Sorting by part of a number in datatables

Tags: datatables

I have a [DataTable](https://datatables.net) where my first column is a VIN number.

Example: FLXVU3822G1000013

Now VIN numbers are just a bunch of information tacked together. The last 6 numbers are the sequence number for that year. You can see that this example vehicle is the 13th one of the year. I'd really like to have my list filtered on those last 6 digits. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this by a custom sorting plugin. In fact you just need to extract the last 6 digits and return them as a number, then dataTables will sort the column using the internal number sorting algorithm :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
 "last-6-digits-pre": function ( a ) {
    var n = a.substring(a.length - 6, a.length)
    return parseInt(n)
 }
})
```

Usage :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs : [
     { targets: 0, type: 'last-6-digits' }
  ]
})
```

where `targets: 0` is the index of the column you want to be sorted this particular way.

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zhmcLkb9/**

Comment: been trying to implement this and I can't seem to get it working so I have a few questions. Why did you tack on -pre to last-6-digits? Where does the jQuery.extend function go in reference to the DataTablie init? Inside the document.ready, outside it, somewhere else...

Comment: @JonD, have updated with a demo.  Try comment out content of `columnDefs`. `pre-` is for "prepare" (as far as I recall) it is called for each row and the returned value will be used when the table is sorted. You can overwrite the sorting algorithms by `-asc` and `-desc` as well. There is to my knowledge not so much documentation of writing plugins (as far as I know) but you can study other plugins here -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/**